# Change element button to image

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to ask how to change an element button to an image using javascript when it's clicked? For example, from Submit button to an image of checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `svg` for demo, you can change it into `<img src="https://some_picture">`

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  button.innerHTML  =`<svg width="50" height="50"></svg>`
});
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `click` event listener to the button that changes its `outerHTML` property:

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.outerHTML = `<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">`
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("contentChange").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

```html
<button id="contentChange" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```